# Adding a new url gives error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

In my urls.py I have this.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from events import views as eviews


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/', include('accounts.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^$', eviews.events_list, name='events_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<o_type>[-\w]+)/$',
        eviews.events_list,
        name='events_list_by_org'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        eviews.event_detail, name='event_detail'),
]
```

when I add the "`user`" url which is at first line in urlpatterns, it shows error on line 26 which is "`events_list_by_org`" url. When I comment out or remove '`user`' url it works fine but shows error when it's included.

Comment: Please post the error traceback

Comment: what error does it shows ?

Comment: it shows syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating your event urls like your accounts url inside `account` app, and adding namespece to `accounts` and `events`.

**urls.py in core**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^user/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),
    url(r'^event/', include('event.urls', namespace='event')),
]
```

**urls.py in event app**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', eviews.events_list, name='events_list'),
    url(r'^(?P<o_type>[-\w]+)/$',
        eviews.events_list,
        name='events_list_by_org'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
        eviews.event_detail, name='event_detail'),
]
```

Maybe it's because of follwoing namespaces, so trying your namespace to user urls.